# Keyboard Avoiding View Shrinking

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like my page to scroll up so that the user can correctly type its email and password. Therefore, I am using KeyboardAvoidingView.
However, when I use it, it shrinks my textinput [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Tzt.jpg) instead of moving up the page. Without the keyboard my app looks like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF0UU.jpg).

My code  following for this page :

```js
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }
    handleEmail = (text) => {
        this.setState({ email: text })
    }
    handlePassword = (text) => {
        this.setState({ password: text })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ImageBackground source={require('../pics/main.png')} style={styles.background}>
                    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{ flex: 1}} >

                        <Text style={styles.title2}>WELCOME</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputEmail}
                            placeholder="Enter Email"
                            onChangeText={this.handleEmail}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            style={[styles.inputEmail, styles.inputPassword]}
                            placeholder="Enter password"
                            onChangeText={this.handlePassword}
                        />
                        <View style={styles.buttons}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.login} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MainScreen')} >
                                <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOGIN</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={styles.login} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpScreen')}>
                                <Text style={styles.loginText}>SIGN UP</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        </KeyboardAvoidingView>

                    </ImageBackground>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    area: {
        flex: 1
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    background: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: "cover",
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    },
    title2: {
        paddingTop: 10,
        color: color.primary,
        fontSize: 25,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    },
    inputEmail: {
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: color.primary,
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: '50%',
        height: '5%',
        marginTop: 100,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        backgroundColor: color.secondary
    },
    inputPassword: {
        marginTop: 10
    },
    buttons: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        marginTop: 30,
        marginLeft: 70,
        marginRight: 70,
    },
    login: {
        borderColor: color.primary,
        borderRadius: 20,
        borderWidth: 2,
        width: '40%',
        height: '118%',
        backgroundColor: color.primary
    },
    loginText: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 1,
        color: 'white'
    }
});
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong ?

UPDATE : to avoid shrinking put the text input container width and height not as a percentage but as real numbers :  inputEmail --> width: 200, height: 35,

Comment: Add KeyboardAvoidingView as your container of your page. Instead of View, add KeyboardAvoidingView. I hope that helps

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does the same thing, shrinking the email and password textbox ...

Comment: I fixed the shrinking problem but the input text box still does not move up when the keyboard comes up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with your code, I have fixed this in this snack with your provided code.

[Expo Snack with CSS fixes to avoid keyboard](https://snack.expo.io/05DPBRSqd)

Comment: I don't know if it works for you but on my iphone it still acts the same way as before...

Comment: Yes I tried. I found that it was shrinking because the height of the inputbox was in % so I put it with numbers directly. However, my keyboardavoidingview still does not bring up the input textbox when the keyboard comes up

Comment: I updated the question so you can see what I mean if I was not clear

Comment: I am using  <KeyboardAvoidingView
                    behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "height" : "height"}
                    style={styles.container}
                > and it still shrink the textinput. @Waheed Akhtar

Comment: Why you put condition even when both condition return same value also on which platform you have this issue and plz share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a prop called `keyboardVerticalOffset`.You can set it to a negative value to make the view move up more when the keyboard appears, or to a positive value to move it down.

I experimented and it was perfect at -210

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView 
     behavior="height"
     keyboardVerticalOffset={-210}>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).